Solution to horizontally expand MudTabs on a Mobile device
so starting off I basically need a way to re-adjust the MudTabs from the code below so it can fit the entire horizontal space of the screen and on top of that it has to adjust to the resolutions of a mobile device (both vertically and horizontally)
I tried many methods but none of them could work as its intented to be. Any recommendations?
Code:
text
I tried to expand the MudTabs using numerous CSS styles and other mudblazor options such as MudContainers, it was expected to look something like this...
Note: This is from the Website, but it's supposed to be adjusted on a mobile device when it is set vertically and when it is set horizontally
